# Visual Studio 2012 Variadic Templates Macro Argument Count

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, visual-studio-2012, variadic-templates

VS2012 supports variadic templates with CTP but if I was to just use the macros, is there a way to determine the number of arguments? For instance, lets say the macro looked like this:

```
#define _ALLOC_MEMBER_CONSTRUCT( \
     TEMPLATE_LIST, PADDING_LIST, LIST, COMMA, CALL_OPT, X2, X3, X4) \
 template<class _Objty COMMA LIST(_CLASS_TYPE)> \
void ConstructSelector(_Objty *_Ptr COMMA LIST(_TYPE_REFREF_ARG)) \
{    \
     BaseClass::construct(_Ptr, LIST(_FORWARD_ARG), /* NUM OF ARGS*/); \
}

    _VARIADIC_EXPAND_0X(_ALLOC_MEMBER_CONSTRUCT, , , , )
    #undef _ALLOC_MEMBER_CONSTRUCT
```

Is there a way to determine the number of arguments for the last paramter? When I looked at xstddef.h (where the macros are defined), it looks like there is no easy way. I am curious if anyone found a way with MS macros.

Comment: I guess the overriding question is... *why*... would you want to hit implementation-specific *anything*, especially something as heinous as this "thing"? Just curious.

Comment: Company is migrating to VS2012 and that was just approved. It would take longer to approve CTP. Figuring this out is a "just in case" the CTP approval doesn't make the deadline.

Comment: Honestly, if that is the case (an approval of toolchain scenario) I would avoid both the CTP and these macros entirely until Herb and crew get their ducks in a row and provide a solution comparable to that of every other reasonable implementation. I can tell you from personal experience that these macros are a royal pita to debug with.

Comment: Have you looked at Boost's Preprocessor library? [`BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/variadic_size.html) seems relevant.